# How do I keep variable below a constant if the variable value is reused?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a code like

```
for(...)
{
    K=K*X; //X is some equation
    answer=answer+K%C;
}
```

The variable `answer` is all I am interested in, while K is only a intermediate value. As you can see, I am interested in only `K%C` not `K`. But I cannot do `K=K%C` in for loop as it will give wrong result. But currently the K value grows very fast and overflows.

How could I control value of K while not getting wrong results either?

Comment: Put `K=K*X;` outside the loop and use `answer=answer+K%C;` in the loop?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The question is clear, with a good snippet. And this sort of thing comes up a lot in scientific programming.

Comment: Why do you say that "I cannot do K=K%C in for loop as it will give wrong result"? As long as K doesn't overflow during the multiplication, reducing it modulo C before the multiplication will not affect its value modulo C afterwards. And overflow during the multiplication is precisely what you want to avoid here.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Maybe because the OP says they cannot use the obvious solution, with no explanation *why* they cannot use it besides "it will give wrong result"? Which in turn implies that they're either mistaken about that, or there's something going on that they haven't told us about, since there's nothing in the code they've posted that would prevent them from reducing K modulo C within the loop.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I think I can't do `K=K%C` after `K=K*X` as it will give wrong value of K in next iteration. answer given by bathsheba works. do point out if I am wrong :)

Comment: IMHO if an approach gives the wrong result then it's not an acceptable solution ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba Your approach works. My approach was giving wrong answers.

Comment: @Bathsheba's answer `K = ((K % C) * (X % C)) % C;` is exactly equivalent to `K = (K % C) * (X % C); K = K % C;` (at least assuming that K, X and C have the same type, and it's not narrower than `int`). So if that answer works for you, then so would `K = K % C;`. Did you actually try it before asking, or did you just assume (for whatever reason) that it wouldn't work?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sorry for the confusion. There were actually two problems. One of which is that the value overflows. While both methods do work to some extent, my method would still cause overflow due to nature of multiplication. The method given in accepted answer does not cause overflow, so it works. As far as the second problem is concerned, it is out of scope of the question but niether method would work for it. anyway this question-answer pair is still useful for me and hopefully for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exploit the identity

`ab mod n = (a mod n)(b mod n) mod n`

And replace `K = K * X;` with `K = ((K % C) * (X % C)) % C;`

Then `answer = answer + K % C;` becomes `answer += K;`

Comment: I started off with that answer, and then figured you could put the `K = (K % C)` part outside the loop, and if `X` is not changed inside the loop, you could also put the `X = (X % C)` part outside the loop... Not that it matters that much, just perhaps a couple of operations less per iteration.

Comment: Indeed, I've understood X to be different on each iteration. But I like your answer; I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
K = K%C;

for (...)
{
    K = K*X%C;
    answer = answer+K;
}
```

Comment: For people who don't have the [C operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) fully memorized, it might be worth explicitly noting that `*` and `%` share the same precedence and are left-associative, so that `K*X%C` is indeed parsed as `(K*X)%C` as it should be. Of course, if it's possible that `X >= C`, then you might need to use `(K*(X%C))%C` to fully eliminate the risk of overflow.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I figured it was obvious that `%` and `/` share the same precedence (since modulo is essentially a dividing operation), hence `%` and `*` share the same precedence... but you're right, it's probably not as obvious.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: With regards to your other suggestion - that's the answer I started off with (more precisely, `K=(K%C)*(X%C)%C`). But then i realized that `K=K%C` could be executed (**once**) outside the loop. You could also do `X=X%C` outside the loop if `X` is not changed inside the loop (not really clear from the question). In any case, inferring from the question, I concluded that OP was a bit of a novice, so I figured I'd keep it as simple as possible. But essentially you're right - `X%C` would eliminate the risk of overflow (again, that's the answer I started off with).

Comment: BTW, it doesn't **fully** eliminate the risk of overflow, if `C` by itself is a very large value.

Comment: True, the type of K (or, more precisely, the type of K*X) needs to be large enough to store at least the number (C-1)^2, otherwise overflow is inevitable. The OP did mention that X in their code was actually a stand-in for a more complicated expression, so I assumed that it probably varies between iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Could not comment on other answer yet, but I believe the initialization of `K = K%C;` outside the loop is not correct.  Just the loop is all you need.

```
for( ... )
{
     K=K*X%C;
     answer=answer+K;
}
```

The reason for why this works is that it's not necessary to accumulate the extra multiples of C within K.  Suppose K is first iteration, and K' is the next iteration, then  K'*X = (K/C)*X + (K%C)*X.  So we can drop the (K/C)*X part in each iteration.

Comment: You need to *somehow* ensure that the initial value of K before the loop is less than C. Whether the best way to do that is to explicitly reduce K modulo C before the loop, or something else, depends on how K is initialized (which the OP hasn't shown us).

Comment: You're right and I agree.  I had assumed that K was initialized such that at least the first iteration would not overflow.  Thanks.